# Junit static import assertTrue failing but Assert.assertTrue passing?

Tags: java, spring, unit-testing, junit, static-import

I have a unit test method as below:

```
 @Test
 public void someTest() throws Exception {
        /* Some code here*/

        List <SomeClass> someClassList = someRepository.findBySomething(param);
        assertTrue("List should not be empty", !someClassList.isEmpty());
//      Assert.assertTrue("List should not be empty", !someClassList.isEmpty());
 }
```

The above test fails.
But if I comment the static import assertion `assertTrue` and un-comment the normal assertion `Assert.assertTrue`, it passes.

I have only added relevant piece of code. Please let me know if more information is needed.

What might be the reason for above behavior?

**EDIT**

Below are the imports I have:

```
 import org.junit.Assert;

 import static org.junit.Assert.assertTrue;
```

Comment: Check that your `import static` and `import` are the same

Comment: Please include the relevant `import static` line in your question

Comment: can it be that this test case is stateful ?